# Why use Failover replica on Google Cloud RDS?

Tags: high-availability, failover, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

we are thinking of migrating our MySQL database from our dedicated server to a Google Cloud RDS instance. However I would like to clarify the below:

1) What is the purpose of creating a failover replica (high availability) at Google Cloud? I mean in a realistic scenario, is it even possible the RDS instance to "break" for any reason?  (Having in mind that we use failover for availability).

2) Is failover replica helping in the performance of the database, or it is used just for availability purposes? For example if I choose the failover replica, will this make my app run faster?

Comment: Even the big cloud services can have unexpected outages in some areas. https://aws.amazon.com/message/41926/